# How do I only run a single go test from command line when multiple go tests start with the same prefix?

Tags: go, command-line

I have several tests in my test suite. Two of these tests are named  `TestBasic` and `TestBasicOne`

When I run this command from command line

```
go test -v -run TestBasic
```

`TestBasic` runs, then `TestBasicOne` executes immediately afterwards, presumably because they share the same prefix

How can I only run `TestBasic` without triggering `TestBasicOne`?

Comment: The -run argument is a regular expression. `go test -v -run "^TestBasic$"`

Comment: @FactsOfLife this answers my question thank you